# Sort HashMap of ArrayList Based on ArrayList5 Size

Tags: java, hashmap

I realize there are questions similar to this, but they do not answer my question.

I need to return the keys of my HashMap, based on the size of the corresponding value's ArrayList. For example, if I have:

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> unsortedMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
unsortedMap.put("A",new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)));
unsortedMap.put("B",new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4)));
unsortedMap.put("C",new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,3,1,4)));
```

I'd like it to return "C" "A" "B"

Comment: `unsortedMap.keySet()`, the rest is trivial. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @m0skit0: The key set here is "A", "B", "C". How do you sort those, when you've thrown away the values?

Comment: @JonSkeet Who said the values have been thrown away? Even in your solution you still use the values...

Comment: @m0skit0: Well you've said the rest is trivial - which suggests building the comparator is trivial, which suggests to me that it doesn't require any extra information. It seems to me that that's *not* the simplest way of doing this... and that even if it were, calling `keySet()` is the trivial part, not the ordering.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, in fact it is not trivial. Still OP didn't show what he has tried.

Comment: @m0skit0: I agree it's far from a great question - but the dismissive "the rest is trivial" doesn't help, IMO. (*Especially* when it's not accurate, but even if it *had* been...)

Comment: @JonSkeet That's why it's a comment and not an answer. Still OP didn't show what he has tried, I don't know why I should make an effort while he/she did not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65880/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-m0skit0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Java 7, you can call [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) to get a `Set<Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<Integer>>>` - which you can then use to populate something like an `ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,ArrayList<Integer>>>` which you can sort with a custom comparator.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> unsortedMap = new HashMap<>();
    unsortedMap.put("A", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    unsortedMap.put("B", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4)));
    unsortedMap.put("C", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 1, 4)));

    List<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>>> list = 
        new ArrayList<>(unsortedMap.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new EntryComparator());

    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : list) {
      System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
  }

  private static class EntryComparator
      implements Comparator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>>>
  {
    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> left,
        Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> right) {     
      // Right then left to get a descending order
      return Integer.compare(right.getValue().size(), left.getValue().size());
    }
  }
}
```

In Java 8 you can use the streams API to make it slightly more fluent - while taking basically the same steps.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> unsortedMap = new HashMap<>();
    unsortedMap.put("A", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    unsortedMap.put("B", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(4)));
    unsortedMap.put("C", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 1, 4)));

    List<String> keys = unsortedMap
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .sorted((left, right) ->
              Integer.compare(right.getValue().size(), left.getValue().size()))
          .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
          .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (String key : keys) {
      System.out.println(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution using `Collections.sort`. But I didn't know that doing other people's homework was the StackOverflow's way... Good to know though :)

Comment: @m0skit0: There's no indication this is homework. I personally think this is a more helpful response than your comment / deleted answer...

Comment: Homework or real work or whatever, it makes no difference. You just did it for him :) An answer is deleted for a reason: I misunderstood the question at first, I thought he only needed the keys.

Comment: @m0skit0: I didn't just do it - I *explained* it as well, in a way which naturally links back to the questions it seems the OP had already found.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It wasn't HW. I wish it was.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), here's also a way to do this:

```
List<String> keys = unsortedMap.entrySet()
                   .stream()
                   .sorted((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e2.getValue().size(), e1.getValue().size()))
                   .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(keys); //[C, A, B]
```

What it does is:

- get a Stream of the entries of your map
- sort the entries by the the size of each arraylist
- map each entry to its corresponding key
- collect the result in a List

If you want you could also write the sorted line as :

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().size(), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my project is built in Java 7.